# Is this a valid probability function?

Tags: probability

Consider an arbitrary function $F$ over a sample space $S$, with the following properties:

- $F(S) = 1$
- There exists some event $B$ such that $F(B) > 1$

I do not think that this is a valid probability function, as there is an event $B$ that has a probability above $1$, which cannot be possible. Is this the right way of approaching this question?

Comment: Of course you are right. I don't understand why you should post this question.

Comment: Maybe the goal is to prove that such a function can't satisfy the axioms of a probability measure. Indeed, it would violate either additivity or non-negativity.

Comment: Depending on how you have seen the axioms of probability stated this may just violate one of the axioms outright. Many people demand a function from a collection of subsets to $[0,1]$ to be a probability function if some other conditions are also true. If $F(B)>1$ then it violates the target-space condition. If you consider discrete probability and $F(A)=\sum_{x \in A} f(x)$ then since $F(S) = F(B) + F(S\setminus B)$ that would require $F(S\setminus B)<0$ which means some of the $f(x)$'s are negative which violates a different axiom.